# How to add custom NOT TINTED image to UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I want to add an image to UIBarButtonItem.

MY CODE:

```
        let button1 = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "icon1"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: "Onb1ClickListener")
    let button2 = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "icon2"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: "Onb2ClickListener")
    let button3 = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "icon3"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: "Onb3ClickListener")

    self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([button1, button2, button3], animated: false)
    self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
```

1. this works but i get tinted blue images. how can i get the original images not tinted?
2. How can i add an image to the left of the UINavigationBar (not a bar button just a image)?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default image rendering case in a `UIBarButtonItem` is `UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate`. So you have to create an image with the rendering options of `UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal`, and set that image to the `UIBarButtonItem`. So:

```
let customImage = UIImage(named: "icon1")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
let button1 = UIBarButtonItem(image: customImage, style: .Plain, target: self, action: "Onb1ClickListener")
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know the answer to my second question?

Comment: I think you cannot add just an image to the navigation bar without hacking it, I would set it as a UIBarButtonItem with an image, but without real functionality.